# Batch How can I get the full path to a Windows service exe (including parameters)

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, service

I would like to get the full path (includig parameters if there are defined one) of a Windows service executable.

My code is as follow :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ('sc qc HomeGroupProvider 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "BINARY_PATH_NAME"') do echo "%%a"
pause
exit
```

The problem is that it doesn't take what is after the exe, as possible parameters.

How to make so that the complete path is taken into account ?

Assume the full path is something like this: C:\Program Files\MyAPP\application.exe /parameter1="xx" /parameter2="xx" OR -parameter1="xx" -parameter2="xx"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `wmic process where name="svchost.exe" get commandline`

Comment: Regarding the above advice, for better output, remove the entries without a command line, i.e. `%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "Name='svchost.exe' And CommandLine Is Not Null" Get CommandLine`

Comment: Try `for /f  … do echo "%a" %b`

Comment: @JosefZ it works ! Thank you so much !